# Android google maps not loading, app signature problem

Tags: android, google-maps, keystore

I currently have two copies of the same program on two separate computers, on one of them the map loads fine but the other it doesnt'.  The only difference between the two is that I went through the application signature steps, while the other I'm using a debug keystore.

Is there a possibility that an unsigned application (but using a working maps api key) with source that originated from a different computer is unable to load maps?

The code works on one computer (emulator included).  Map loads.
I have internet.
Android 2.2, emulator and phone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you obtained a separate Google Maps API key based on the debug store and put that key in the source on  the machine that does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the api key is specific for each computer.  i.e. when I move from one location to another I keep info on each api key.. ex.    etc.. etc.. I have to use the correct key depending on which computer I'm on.